# Git diff - include only a specific file type meanwhile exclude a folder

Tags: git

I'm writing a script and need `git diff` command to show me file(s) that:

1. has extension '.ts'
2. is not inside the "test" folder

I know I could do the fulfill the first requirement alone with `git diff -w origin/master *.ts`, and the second alone with `git diff -w origin/master ":(exclude)test/**"`.

But I'm struggling with making it meet the two requirements together. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

My git version is 2.27.0.windows.1

Comment: doesn't `git diff -w origin/master *.ts ":(exclude)test/**"` do exactly what you want ?

Comment: No it doesn't exclude test folder with this command

Comment: ok, which shell are you working in?

Comment: @philb You'd better avoid shell-related problems completely by passing `*.ts` to Git instead of the shell: `git diff -w origin/master "*.ts" ":(exclude)test/**`

Comment: Yes, that was going to be my next suggestion (in fact switching to single quotes) but I wanted the OP to confirm they were in a POSIX shell and not cmd or PowerShell on Windows

Comment: I was using cmd, Just tried using Git bash and switching to single quotes but got the same result.

Comment: I'm not sure offhand how pathspecs combine. That is, given instructions that say "include `*foo*`, but exclude `*bar*`", does `foo-the-bar` fall under the include or the exclude rule? Does the order of the rules matter? Perhaps first or last rule wins. Experimentation would be useful here; documentation as to intent would be even more useful, but that's just missing.

Comment: tested on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04, git 2.35.0) : `git diff -w origin/master "*.ts" ":(exclude)test/**"` works as you intend (scans all `*.ts` files in tree, ignores files under `test/`)

Comment: I just tried in cmd and both `git diff -w origin/master "*.ts" ":(exclude)test/**"` and `git diff -w origin/master "*.ts" ":(exclude)test/*"` (single star at the end) work. At this point we would need an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you further...